# Eclipse shows Exceptions in wrong line

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

Eclipse 4.2.2 (used with Oracle JDK 1.7.0) shows Exceptions thrown within a `synchronized`-Block in the wrong line, the beginning of the block.

In real-world examples, it's not always easy to spot the line where the exception occurred.
Is there any way to get Eclipse to show the actual line where the exception was thrown?

---

Minimal working example:

```
  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test = new Test();
      test.test();
    }

    void test() {
      synchronized (this) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
      }
    }
  }
```

Eclipse shows the exception here:

[image: exception in line "synchronized (this)"]

Stack trace:

[image: stack trace]

Comment: have you tried to recompile your class? it could be because you've built the project and then modified the lines.

Comment: is this your code for which the exception is shown, or some downloaded api for which it is shown

Comment: It's my code, and I tried cleaning the project and re-executing.

Comment: Provide more code and the stack trace

Comment: Why are you synchronizing to throw an exception? Also this shows where the thread is suspended and not the stacktrace of the exception. Let it run and when the exception is thrown, print the stacktrace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screenshot you have is not the exception, but is the Debug view. It is showing you where the current line of execution is and that is correct. The RuntimeException has been thrown and now execution is unravelling back to the top. In the screeenshot, execution has reached line 9.

The Console view in Eclipse shows the excepion and that correctly lists line 10.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
at LineNumber.test(LineNumber.java:10)
at LineNumber.main(LineNumber.java:5)
```

You can't inspect the Exception directly here (as far as I know) because it's not being captured in a variable). But if you go to Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Open Popup When Suspended on Exception, Eclipse will create a pop containing the Exception (with correct line numbers) which you can inspect/drill into